# some errors in the overleaf documents

Tags: unicode, overleaf

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,oneside, reqno]{amsart}
    \usepackage[left=2.7cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[dutch,polish,swedish,french,german,russian,main=english]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[tipa,combine]{ucs}
    \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
    \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={green!55!black},citecolor={green!55!black},urlcolor={green!55!black}}  
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,bm}
    \usepackage{thmtools}
    \usepackage{environ}
    \usepackage{nicefrac}  
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{bbm}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{microtype} 
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \makeatletter
    \let\mytagform@=\tagform@
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{green!55!black}(#1)}}
    \makeatother
    \renewcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{green!55!black}}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
    \newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
    \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
    \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
    \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
    \newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
    \newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
    \parindent0mm
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    
    \titleformat{\chapter}
      {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\sffamily\bfseries}
      {\thechapter}
      {1em}
      {}
    
    \titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\fontsize{10}{15}\sffamily\bfseries}
      {\thesection}
      {1em}
      {}
    
    \titleformat{\subsection}
      {\normalfont\fontsize{10}{15}\sffamily\bfseries\slshape}
      {\thesubsection}
      {1em}
      {}`enter code here`
```

Hello! I am using the above template and I am getting the following errors in the overleaf file,

```
(1)LaTeX Error: Command `\lll' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.156 ...mbol{\lll}          {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"6E}
                                                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


(2)LaTeX Error: \eqnumcolor undefined.
 X manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.36 \renewcommand{\eqnumcolor}
                               {\color{green!55!black}}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

\c@theorem=\count160
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2016/03/21 v2.10.2 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box45
\beforetitleunit=\skip74
\aftertitleunit=\skip75
\ttl@plus=\dimen268
\ttl@minus=\dimen269
\ttl@toksa=\toks56
\titlewidth=\dimen270
\titlewidthlast=\dimen271
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen272
) (/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

(3) Misplaced alignment tab character &.

You have placed an alignment tab character '&' in the wrong place. If you want to align something, you must write it inside an align environment such as \begin{align} … \end{align}, \begin{tabular} … \end{tabular}, etc. If you want to write an ampersand '&' in text, you must write \& instead.

 Learn more
l.704 \newblock {\em Chaos, Solitons &
                                       Fractals}, 4(10):1965 -- 1968, 1994.
I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.


(4) Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ℓ (U+2113)

(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1506 ...iterated function systems defined on ℓ
                                                  ∞-sum of a
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

(5) Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ∞ (U+221E)

(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1506 ...rated function systems defined on ℓ∞
                                                  -sum of a
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

(6) Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ̧ (U+327)

(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1806 Maciej Sļ
                  eczka.
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Thanks for any help to remove such errors. especially it would be great to help me to construct my usepackages lists and others to get an error-free output in the overleaf. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The initial error is an incompatibility between `babel`/`polish` and the `amssymb` package, as you can observe with this minimal example:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[polish]{babel}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \begin{document}
   \end{document}
   ```

   Add the following lines after loading the `babel` package.

   ```
   \usepackage[dutch,polish,swedish,french,german,russian,main=english]{babel}
   \let\plll\lll
   \let\lll\relax
   ```
2. Regarding the second error `\eqnumcolor` undefined, replace `\renewcommand` by `\newcommand` (line 36 of the code that you posted)
3. In the bibliography, in the string `Chaos, Solitons & Fractals`, replace `&` by `\&`.
4. Apparently you are writing mathematics. In this case, use math mode and the commands provided for math symbols. Instead of ℓ∞, you maybe meant to write `$\ell_\infty$` (polish l subscript infinity) or `$\ell^\infty$` (polish l superscript infinity). If the l symbol was the only reason for including `polish` among the options of the `babel` package, then remove it and you don't need the first fix above.
5. In the name `Maciej Sļeczka`, don't use the letter `l` followed for the unicode for a cedille, but the letter `ļ` that already includes the cedille (e.g., copy it from this post if you don't know how to type it).

Comment: Thanks so much, one error removed!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MissQ If there are more errors, than we need more information. Maybe make a copy of your document on overleaf, remove sensitive parts and post the link to the document. For the other errors that you posted, it is not clear whether they arise from the snippet that you posted.

Comment: @MissQ Regarding the second error `\eqnumcolor` undefined, replace `\renewcommand` by `\newcommand` (line 36 of the code that you posted).

Comment: Thanks so much, another error vanishedddddddddddddddddd

Comment: I have given a screenshot if that helps?

Comment: Usually the source code (and reproducing the error oneself) of more helpful. But in this case, doesn't the first error message exactly say what the problem and the fix is? Apparently, you have `Chaos, Solitons & Fractals` somewhere in your bibliography, and the `&` should read `\&`.

Comment: Hello solution no 4 is still not working by replacing l to \ell ....rest of the errors gone... @article{Bahsoun2011,
  title={Invariant densities and escape rates: rigorous and computable approximations in the ${\ell}^{\infty}$-norm},
  author={Bahsoun, Wael and Bose, Christopher},
  journal={Nonlinear Analysis: Theory, Methods \& Applications},
  volume={74},
  number={13},
  pages={4481--4495},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

Comment: I don't have a crystal ball that shows me the rest of your document. When I take your preamble, apply the fixes above and complete it with the lines `\begin{document}
\cite{Bahsoun2011}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bbb}
\end{document}` and put your reference into the file `bbb.bib`, then everything works (running `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`). What is the error message? Maybe post a new question, with the relevant portions of the code.